# Count Values for Each Number in a cell in a Column

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet like the following, and would like to go down each row and add 1 to each of the numbers listed under the L3 column. Eventually, I would like to output something like this:

```
L3s    Count    Attr Ids
4770     10     [370, 380, ...]
6420     8      [481, 490...]
21253    20      [580....290]
...     ...      ...
```

The count is derived by going through all of the rows, and adding 1 to each L3 number whenever it is encountered. Attr IDs are the ids that contributed to the count. Is there any simple way to accomplish this in excel without having to vba/python?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You could count the number of "," in column "C". Or do you want to count the unique values?

Comment: Hi, I was looking to add 1 for each time i see a L3 number, and also remember which attr_id contributed to that, so that I can create a final list with L3 ids, total counts and attri_id.

Comment: I'm not understanding the desired results. For example 4770 only occurs at row 2 with attr_id 370. So why is it concatenated with `380` in your results while the L3 there is not the same?

Comment: Hi, the desired results are just to show the format, but i've not gone to actually sieve out the correct data, thanks

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have windows Excel O365, you can use the following formulas:

(Note that I made the original data into a Table)

***Sorted Unique list of the L3s:***

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Table1[L3s])," ",""),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

***Count of the L3s***

```
=COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Table1[L3s])," ",""),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.=" & F8 &"]"))
```

***Associate Attr IDs***

```
="[" &TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(Table1[attr],ISNUMBER(FIND(","&F8&",",SUBSTITUTE(","&Table1[L3s]& ","," ","")))))&"]"
```

[image]